# Probability of final outcome of a game of two halves

Tags: probability

Consider a game which is played in 2 halves between two teams, A and B. The outcome of the 2nd half of the game is independent of the outcome of the 1st half.

Each team can score between 0 and N points in each half, and the probability of scoring exactly M is known and equal to $P_1^A(M)$ for team A and $P_1^B(M)$ for team B in the first half, and $P_2^A(M)$ and $P_2^B(M)$ respectively in the 2nd half.

The final score is the sum of each teams' scores. So, if team A scores once in the first half and twice in the 2nd, while team B score twice in the first and not at all in the 2nd half, then the final score will be 2-2. Thus the lowest possible scoring match is 0-0 and this  an only occur when the first half is 0-0 and the 2nd half is 0-0. Similar logic applies where, if $N=4$ for example, the final score is 8-8

However, there are many possible combinations for final scores between 0-0 and 8-8. I wish to compute the probabilities for every possible final score.

I know that there are $(N+1)^4$ possible combinations in total, but the only way I have been able to work out the probabilities of each combination is by hand in a spreadsheet with actual numbers. For example, I know when N=4 there are 10 possible ways of making a final score of 7-4 (which is Not the same as 4-7 obviously) can occur in 10 ways, so I just compute the product of those 10 probabilities (3-0 and 4-4, 3-1 and 4-3, 3-2 and 4-2, 3-3 and 4-1, 3-4 and 4-0, 4-0 and 3-4, 4-1 and 3-3, 4-2 and 3-2, 4-3 and 3-1, 4-4 and 3-0).

I would like to find a way to do this more easily, and feel that there should be some formulas I can apply, just from knowing $N$ and each of the underlying probabilities, but so far I didn’t find anything.

BTW this isn't homework, it's just something i am interested in.

Comment: "The final score is the sum of each teams' scores. So if team A scores once in the first half and twice in the 2nd, while team B score twice in the first and not at all in the 2nd half, then the final score will be 2-2."—shouldn't the final score be 3-2? ... and ... "Similar logic applies where the final score is 8-8."—are you taking $N=4$?

Comment: @GregMartin yes ! Sorry, I will update the questions...

Answer (score 2):

Since the scoring for $A$ and $B$ are independent, we can treat them independently, and then multiply the results after.

For $P(A)$, the total probability of getting score $M$ across the board is $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^M P_1^A(n)\cdot P_2^A(M-n)$$

So the total answer is $$\bigg(\sum\limits_{n=0}^M P_1^A(n)\cdot P_2^A(M-n) \bigg)\cdot \bigg(\sum\limits_{n=0}^M P_1^B(n)\cdot P_2^B(M-n)\bigg)$$

Note that if $n>N$, then $P_1^A(n)=P_2^A(n)=P_1^B(n)=P_2^B(n)=0$. This should address @JoeKing's concerns.

Comment: Thank you, this looks great, but I perhaps haven't understood it properly. If we let $N=2$ and set all probabilities equal for each half, and we want the probability for the final score P(0-0), doesn't this give (0.25 x 0.25) x (0.25 x 0.25) which doesn't seem right ? Also, surely the formula should include $N$ ?

Comment: @JoeKing It shouldn't matter, since we would obviously set the probability of $n>N$ to be 0, as in my edit.  Additionally, where did you get the probability of 0.25 from? This was not specified!

Comment: I was just using the example of N=2, so that there are 4 possible outcomes in each half, so that the probability of each outcome in each half is 0.25 (same for the 2nd half)

Comment: @JoeKing There are only three possibilities...0,1,2...I don't understand

Comment: I'm sure it's just me beeing stupid, but I though like this. N=1, so first half results can be one of 0-0, 0-1, 1-0, and 1-1, and I am giving equal probablity (0,25 each) to them to keep it simple. I must be just mising something obvious !#

Comment: comment prior to the last one should have said N=1 !

Comment: @JoeKing Yea you definitely are messing things up. Remember that $P_1^A$ in the case of $N=1$ only has two possibilities... 0 or 1. So suppose either is equally likely, i.e., 50%. So the probability is $0.5^4$. Why does that make sense? Remember that $A$ has to get 0 points for two halves, and so does $B$. That's 4 times that we have to get lucky and get 0 points. Do you get it?

Comment: @JoeKing 1-1 is the most likely, and 0-0 and 2-2 are the least.

Comment: But in a match with N=1, we can get the following 1st half results: 0-0, 1-0, 0-1 and 1-1 (all with prob 0.25 lets say). Same for the 2nd half. So the only way that the *final score* can be 0-0 is is the first half is 0-0 (p=0.25) *and* the 2nd half is also 0.0 (with p=0.25) so 0.0625. Is this wrong ?

Comment: @JoeKing That's correct...That is equal to $0.5^4=0.0625$...What is the problem?

Comment: I think I am nearly there. My struggle is that for each half there are 4 outcomes each with p=0.25, so to get 0-0 as the final match score it must be 0.25*0.25 (same for 1-1) (which is the same as yours, but I don't know why do 0.5^4. Then, to get 0-1 final score it can only come from P( 0-0 and then 0-1) OR P(0-1 and then 0-0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82200/discussion-between-rushabh-mehta-and-joe-king).

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_1(K,L)$ be the probability that team A scores $K$ in the the first half and team B scores $L$ in the first half; then we have the generating function identity
$$
\sum_{K=0}^N \sum_{L=0}^N P_1(K,L) x^K y^L = \bigg( \sum_{K=0}^N P_1^A(K) x^K \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{L=0}^N P_1^B(L) y^L \bigg)
$$
(which is just a fancy way of saying that $P_1(K,L) = P_1^A(K) P_1^B(L)$). A similar formula applies for $P_2(K,L)$, the probability that team A scores $K$ in the the second half and team B scores $L$ in the second half.

Since the total scores are the sum of these two subscores, the corresponding generating functions multiply. In other words, if $P(S,T)$ is the probability that team A scores $S$ in total and team B scores $T$ in total, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{S=0}^{2N} \sum_{T=0}^{2N} P(S,T) x^S y^T &= \bigg( \sum_{K=0}^N \sum_{L=0}^N P_1(K,L) x^K y^L \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{K=0}^N \sum_{L=0}^N P_2(K,L) x^K y^L \bigg) \\
&= \bigg( \sum_{K=0}^N P_1^A(K) x^K \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{K=0}^N P_2^A(K) x^K \bigg)  \bigg( \sum_{L=0}^N P_1^B(L) y^L \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{L=0}^N P_2^B(L) y^L \bigg).
\end{align*}
One simply has to expand the polynomial on the right-hand side to determine any particular coefficient $P(S,T)$.

Of course, this gives the formula from Rushabh Mehta's answer. But this is probably an easier calculation to code in some languages, especially if you want many probabilities $P(S,T)$; and it always helps to understand where these formulas come from and how helpful generating functions can be.

Comment: Generating Functions are the bomb in counting questions

Comment: Aaaaaah Generating Functions ! It seems like this is what I have been missing. Thank you !

Comment: I am slightly confused about how to apply these formula (with `x` and `y`). I might be reminded of the binomial theorem form a previous life (is there a connection? I feel like I am on the cusp of "getting it" but there is just that breakthrough needed hah